# ZK upload=true not working IE10

Tags: java, file-upload, internet-explorer-10, zk

In my webapp I have the following code:

```
<toolbarbutton id="CD" upload="true" image="/static/img/icons/document--plus.png" disabled="false" />
```

The problem is thet when I click on the button nothing happens, but if I test this code on the zk sandbox it works. 
Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks so much,

Daniele

PS The following code works

```
<button id="CD" upload="true" image="/static/img/icons/document--plus.png" disabled="false" />
```

Comment: Can you post some program which not working in IE10

Comment: the code I posted before doesn't work in ie10

Answer (score 0):

```
draggable="true"
```

Make parent component draggable.

```
<div draggable="true"><button upload="></button></div>
```